# PHP + Shell script

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to send a variable in shell command and get output on screen. When I white ping `ping -c 5 google.com` it's working, but when a put variable `$username` it's not. Why my variable is not working?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="7.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$result = shell_exec('ping -c 5 $username');
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This is an **enormous** security risk. What if I post `; rm -rf /` to your script?

Comment: Thanks for information! I'll try to do something with it

Answer (score 3):

You are using single quotes, you need to concatenate the $username or use double quotes

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$result = shell_exec('ping -c 5 ' . $username);
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: It's true. Wrong quotes. Thanks kaseOga.